# Can't add pattern as background image Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, background-image

So, I am trying to accomplish this simple task, that is, setting the background image to be a pattern and repeat it. When I view the template separately ( not through the play app) it works just fine. I must be missing a simple point in play, hopefully you guys/gals can help me. The file is a .png file(binding_dark.png) and is in the folder: binding_dark.This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('binding_dark/binding_dark.png');background-repeat: repeat;">
    hello
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as the template works fine without the framework, it mostly likely has to do with the relative path to the asset directory (`binding_dark/binding_dark.png`).  I, too, have had this problem and it took some experimentation to figure it out.

In the title it says you are using Play Framework.  Using the Assets controller will help alleviate this issue with the root path to the asset.  For example, use `@routes.Assets.at("binding_dark/binding_dark.png")` in your template (assuming you have a sub-folder in your `public` folder called `binding_dark` or, if not, that you updated the route in `routes.conf` to the full path of the image from the public directory in the Play app.

If you must hard-code the path to the asset, and assuming you kept the "stock" assets route in the `routes.conf` file, try using the path: `/assets/binding_dark/binding_dark.png` and see if that works.

Also, if its a path issue, you can use Chrome Developer Tools Console (Settings -> Tools -> Developer Tools -> Console), then load (or reload) the page and you should see in there which assets the page could not load properly due to being unable to find them, etc.

Comment: switching to: @routes.Assets.at("binding_dark/binding_dark.png") solved the problem. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would just be to include the following lines in your css file

```
background-image: url("../binding_dark/binding_dark.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
```

You don't need to use the `@routes.Assets.at()` when using setting background image in play framework views